# Windows phone webcontrol format exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have been using this code for a while working perfectly in my windows phone 7 app im constructing. However all of a sudden it stops working and gives me a format exception error? What i have i been doing wrong since i haven't change a bit in this code since it last worked perfectly?

```
String url = String.Format("http://www.bing.com/search?q={0}"); 
        webBrowser1.Source = (new Uri(string.Format(url), UriKind.Absolute));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `String.Format` method but you don't specify any argument after the string.

I think you are trying to do something like

```
String url = String.Format("http://www.bing.com/search?q={0}", keyword);
```